# AWS ACM once I've deleted a certificate for a given sub domain and I can't create a new certificate for that sudomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-certificate-manager

I'm using AWS certificate manager to create a certificate for an API gateway instance I'm running. The domain is all set up via Route53. If I create a certificate for test.my-domain.com and click the "create records in route53" button the records are added and I get verified. However if I delete that certificate and try to create a new one for the same subdomain The cname records name and value is the same as the deleted one and it fails to add and the full certificate creation fails. I've tried manually adding the records myself incase that fixed the issue but it doesn't. In that instance the Pending validation phase never completes. Is this the expected behaviour?

Any support on this would be great.

Thank you,

I've tried deleting a certificate and readding the certificate via the console. I would expect that the new certificate is verified using the DNS records in route53.

Comment: That's not expected behavior. You should be able to create multiple certificates in ACM with the same domain name. And since the DNS records required for validation will be the same they should validate just fine after the DNS records for the first certificate have been created successfully. From experience, I've seen it work exactly this way. You should use a DNS testing tool like this to make sure the validation records are resolving correctly https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSCheck.aspx

Comment: I've verified the validation cname records and the DNS via the tool you suggested. As I say I can create new certificates for subdomains no problem and they validate via the cname records created on Route53. If I delete that certificate and then recreate it it won't validate.